# Javascript mouseMoved Function

Tags: javascript

I need to fill in the blanks to complete the `mouseMoved` function.

I tried to complete it but I know it's completely wrong! Someone please help me and I'm sorry for the newbie question :(

**Project Description:**

Make it paint!
Now you'll actually make this program paint! Add a `mouseMoved` function that:
- changes the paintbrush x and y properties based on the current mouse position, using the `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables;
- calls the painting function, `paintCanvas`;

Tip: Check the documentation if you're not sure how to use `mouseMoved`.

```
 mouseMoved = function() {
        paintBrush._____ =  _____;
        paintBrush._____ =  _____;
        _____;
        };



    var paintBrush = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    img: getImage("avatars/leaf-red")

    mouseMoved = function() {
        paintBrush.x = MouseX;
        paintBrush.y = MouseY;
        paintCanvas;
    };



var paintCanvas = function() {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(paintBrush.img, paintBrush.x, paintBrush.y);
    };

    paintCanvas();
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why Python was added as a tag but Javascript is the only tag now, sorry about that.

Comment: "_but I know it's completely wrong_" Please explain how you know this. Are you getting errors? Weird behavior? Be specific.

Comment: It would've said "You've completed this step" at the bottom if it was correct. https://imgur.com/a/jRTK9 Here's all it says, sorry I can't post any images yet, there's the imgur link though.

Comment: Honestly, the only thing I see that's wrong is you should have `paintCanvas` as `paintCanvas()` in your answer, as you are calling a function. Also, please mention any javascript frameworks you are using next time. This seems to be processing.js.

Comment: Thank you for replying NaN, I tried making the correction you suggested but it's still not letting me proceed, it's still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part is the

```
mouseMoved = function() {
    paintBrush._____ =  _____;
    paintBrush._____ =  _____;
    _____;
    };
```

function. Essentially, you need to call this function and pass in the arguments for the coordinates of the cursor. Then, set the properties of the `paintBrush` object to those arguments.

Here is a working example....

```js
/*mouseMoved = function() {
        paintBrush._____ =  _____;
        paintBrush._____ =  _____;
        _____;
        };
*/

//init the object...
var paintBrush = {};

//it's good practice to always incldue an onload event before doing anything involving elements on the page...
window.addEventListener('load',init());


function init(){
  //add a global mousemove event...
  window.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMoved);
  //remember! The event object containing the coordinates you want is passed with the event object. The event object is implied. Note that I have "e" in the function argument.
  function mouseMoved(e){
    paintBrush.x = e.clientX;//get the cursor's x coord.
    paintBrush.y = e.clientY;//get the cursor's y coord.
    console.log(paintBrush.x+'\n'+paintBrush.y+'\n');
    //repaint the canvas...
  }
}
```

Side note: I'm a high school senior and I've been teaching myself JavaScript since I was 12. There are many resources online for JavaScript. Congratulations on using SO. The community here is great. Good luck with your studies!

Comment: www139, that's really impressive how long you've been teaching yourself Javascript! Thank you for answering as well. I entered in the code like you said to but it's still not taking it. I think it might be the Khan Academy program it's really wierd.

Comment: Sometimes, the online editors already wrap your JavaScript in hidden "onload" event handlers. It could be that the code never runs. Check the console. Try entering it on Jsfiddle (set no wrap in head to avoid the pre-wrapped onload handler) or Codepen.

Comment: You probably are right, and I've used Jsfiddle before as well and I like it so much better! Unfortunately, the assignment can only be submitted through the Khan Academy program, I"m about to pull my hair out, ugh.

Comment: Check the console. Try putting an obvious `alert` at the beginning of the program. Isolate and find where it stops working.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks for all your help again, you're so nice!